# Substrings and indexes

Tags: c#, string, java-me

I'm creating a Mobile website using J2me, ASP and WML.

I read from a DB and created a string as the following so I can later call it.

```
                string id = reader[0].ToString();
                string name = reader[1].ToString();
                Response.Write("#" + name + id);
```

in J2me I recall it as

```
stringItem3.setText("Welcome  "+result.substring(result.indexOf("#")+1)
  + "ID " + result.substring(result.indexOf("#")+2));
```

and the results are not as I wanted I tried to change  a lot with the syntax but with no luck.

the results always show as

[image]

while what I really want to show is something like

```
Welcome  (name)  ID : (id)
or
Welcome  Arin  ID : 20111
```

What is the best way to get the right results?

And can I later save the id value in a string inside J2me to use it later (yes/No)?

---

I changed the string (solved)

```
string id = reader[0].ToString();
string name = reader[1].ToString();
Response.Write("*"+ id + "#" + name);
```

and when getting the info

```
stringItem3.setText("Welcome  "+result.substring(result.indexOf("#")+1)
  + "ID " + result.substring(result.indexOf("*")+1,result.indexOf("#")));

result.substring(result.indexOf("*")+1,result.indexOf("#")));
```

which is mean to get the chars between "*" and the "#"

now the results are fine as below fig.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you're saving looks like `#Arin20111`, so `indexOf("#")+2` is the 2<sup>nd</sup> character after the `#`.

So `result.substring(result.indexOf("#")+1)` is the *entire* string after the `#`, which is the name *and* ID.  And `result.substring(result.indexOf("#")+1)` is the same string except for the `A` at the beginning.

If you know the name will never contain a `#`, you might store the string as `#Arin#20111`.  Then the name is everything after the `<sup>st</sup>`#`and before the 2<sup>nd</sup>`#`, and the ID is everything after the 2<sup>nd</sup>`#`.

Comment: Thanks for the hints I posted what I did in the question.